# The following method did not exist: com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings.getDescription()Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, querydsl

I use this dependency in my `spring-boot 2.6.2` with `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

`querydsl-mongodb` uses `mongo-java-driver 3.12.8` but `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` uses `mongodb-driver-core`

I get exception

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:
    com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.createCluster(DefaultClusterFactory.java:182)
The following method did not exist:
    com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings.getDescription()Ljava/lang/String;
The calling method's class, com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory, was loaded from the following location:
    jar:file:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app1/WEB-INF/lib/mongo-java-driver-3.12.8.jar!/com/mongodb/connection/DefaultClusterFactory.class
The called method's class, com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings, is available from the following locations:
    jar:file:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app1/WEB-INF/lib/mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar!/com/mongodb/connection/ClusterSettings.class
    jar:file:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app1/WEB-INF/lib/mongo-java-driver-3.12.8.jar!/com/mongodb/connection/ClusterSettings.class
The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:
    com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings: file:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app1/WEB-INF/lib/mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar
Action:
Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory and com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings
```

Comment: It is due to the fact that getDescription() method in ClusterSettings could be missing, try with the newer version of it to see if it has the above method.

Comment: The mongodb driver / integration is outdated. This is a known issue, but due to the many forks of mongodb drivers out there, there is no clear path forward with backwards compatibility still. As a result, no one has touched this issue yet. There seems to be a workaround by excluding the driver dependency that Querydsl ships from your project (https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/3134).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the dependency `org.mongodb mongo-java-driver`
included with `querydsl-mongodb`.
Here https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/3134 the corresponding issue on GitHub but it does not seem to be actively
discussed.

In order to fix this issue you have to exclude the above dependency and add the `org.mongodb mongo-driver-core` dependency as a replacement.

Here the important parts of my pom.xml working with `Spring-Boot 2.7.3`
and `MongoDB v5.0.8`

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>18</java.version>
    <querydsl.version>5.0.0</querydsl.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```